# How can I convert a complex number into an exponent form

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, complex

When I have an expression such as

```
(1/4 + I/4) ((1 - 2 I) x + Sqrt[3] y)
```

it is hard to get an intuition of the number.

So I want to convert it to the complex exponent notation:

$$\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} e^{-\frac{i \pi }{12}} x+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} e^{\frac{i \pi }{4}} y$$

and I also want to convert $(-1)^{1/4}$ to $\exp \left(\frac{i \pi }{4}\right)$.

How can I do it with *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 24):

This explicitly converts any numeric quantities in the expression to the desired form:

```
polarForm = Expand[# /. z_?NumericQ :> Abs[z] Exp[I Arg[z]]] &;
```

e.g.

```
(1/4 + I/4) ((1 - 2 I) x + Sqrt[3] y) // polarForm
```

> $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} e^{\frac{i \pi }{4}-i \text{ArcTan}[2]} x+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} e^{\frac{i \pi }{4}} y$

```
(-1)^(1/4) // polarForm
```

> $e^{\frac{i \pi }{4}}$

Comment: sorry if I'm wrong because I'm not sure about these terms in English, but isn't this an exponential form, not polar?

Comment: @user907860, both terms are valid I believe.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the definitions together with `ComplexExpand` :

```
z = (1/4 + I/4) ((1 - 2 I) x + Sqrt[3] y);
abs = ComplexExpand[Abs[z]]
arg = ComplexExpand[Arg[z], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
(* Sqrt[4 x^2 + (x + Sqrt[3] y)^2]/(2 Sqrt[2]) *)
(* ArcTan[3 x + Sqrt[3] y, -x + Sqrt[3] y] *)

(* check *)
z - abs Exp[I arg] // FullSimplify
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Side note: since _v10.1_ we have `AbsArg`.

Answer (score 2):

The requisite conversion functions are already included in [David Park's *Presentations* add-on](http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html):

```
<<Presentations`
PolarToExp @ ComplexToPolar[(1/4 + I/4) ((1 - 2 I) x + Sqrt[3] y)]
```

(The *Presentations* actually includes a polar form for a complex number of modulus `r` and argument `theta` that displays in the form `r \[Angle] theta`. And `ComplexToPolar` yields that form. Hence the need for the outside function `PolarToExp`. Thus there is a distinction made between "polar form" and "exponential form" -- as there should be.)