# Calculations with "Quantities" Run Slow. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: units

This code plots a 1000 point black body radiation curve in 0.7 seconds.

```
h = 6.62*10^-34
c = 2.99792458*10^8
k = 1.38064880*10^-23
T = 3000.
Isubν[ν_] := ((2 h ν^3)/c^2) 1/(E^((h ν)/(k T)) - 1)

Plot[Isubν[ν], {ν, 1*10^13, 1*10^15}, AxesOrigin -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 1000,
     MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

However, using `Quantities` with units, the following code takes 19 seconds for just 200 points. What am I doing wrong?

```
h = Quantity[6.62*10^-34, "Joules"*"Seconds"]
c = Quantity[2.99792458*10^8, "Meters"/"Seconds"]
k = Quantity[1.38064880*10^-23, "Joules"/"Kelvins"]
T = Quantity[3000, "Kelvins"]

Isubν[ν_] := ((2 h (Quantity[ν, "Hertz"])^3)/c^2) 1/(E^((h (Quantity[ν, "Hertz"]))/(k T)) - 1)

Plot[Isubν[ν], {ν, 1.0*10^13, 1.0*10^15}, AxesOrigin -> {1.*10^13, 0.},
     PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

Comment: Units are slow, I'm afraid. By the way, Planck's constant, the speed of light, and Boltzmann's constant are built in: `Quantity[1, "PlanckConstant"]`, `Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"]` and `Quantity[1, "BoltzmannConstant"]`. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16446/are-mathematica-9-and-10-units-really-slow

Comment: As noted, these ones are on the slow side, unfortunately. Consider reformulating so that you are doing computations with natural units, or nondimensional quantities. (`QuantityMagnitude[]` is particularly useful.) There is also the new `PlanckRadiationLaw[]` function.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Patrick. I wrote the code first using the built in constants, then took them out to see if they were the culprit. I submitted my question with "typed-in" constants, just for simplicity, but thanks anyhow. I have looked at the question you referenced for me. A lot to study there. Many thanks. Bill

Comment: J.M.: PlanckRadiationLaw[ ]: Way cool, didn't know about it. Thanks.