# Wrapper for inexact numeric complex numbers that maintains polar form

Tags: output-formatting, complex

Related question:
[How can I convert a complex number into an exponent form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16414/how-can-i-convert-a-complex-number-ab-i-to-the-exponent-form-a-expi-phi/16419#16419)

*Mathematica* insists on displaying complex number in form `a+I b` when `a` or `b` are not exact:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
z = 3 + 4 I;
Abs[z] Exp[I Arg[z]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
z = 3.0 + 4 I;
Abs[z] Exp[I Arg[z]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What I'd like is a `polarForm` wrapper that keeps the polar form even when `a` or `b` are not exact, like this:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
(z = 3.0 + 4 I) // polarForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(z = 3 + 4 I) // polarForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the above, `polarForm` is the wrapper needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specify the display format of something using `MakeBoxes`, like so:

```
MakeBoxes[polarForm[z_Complex], form_] := 
 With[{r = Abs[z], ϕ = Arg[z]}, 
  RowBox[{If[r == 1, Sequence @@ {}, MakeBoxes[r, form]], 
    If[ϕ == 0, Sequence @@ {}, 
     SuperscriptBox[MakeBoxes[E, form], 
      RowBox[{MakeBoxes["\[ImaginaryI]", form], 
        If[ϕ == 1, Sequence @@ {}, 
         MakeBoxes[ϕ, form]]}]]]}]]

Sqrt[5] E^(I ArcTan[2]) // N // polarForm
(* 2.23607E^(I1.10715) *)
```

Comment: +1 -- FYI you can use `##&[]` in place of `Sequence @@ {}` -- see [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6078678/618728) and [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8877880/618728), and the comments below.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative:

```
polarForm[z_] := Module[{rt, f},
          If[Im[z] == 0 && Positive[Re[z]], Return[z]];
          rt = Through[{Abs, Arg}[z]];
          f = Which[
                    rt[[1]] == 1, Defer[E^(I #2)] &,
                    rt[[2]] == 1, Defer[#1 E^I] &,
                    True, Defer[#1 E^(I #2)] &];
          f @@ rt]
```

`Sqrt[5] E^(I ArcTan[2]) // N // polarForm` using this version should yield the same result as in Xerxes's answer. The upshot of this method is that the output can be copied and used as executable input, thanks to `Defer[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use David Park's Presentations add-on (see http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html):

```
   << Presentations`
   ComplexToPolar[3 + 4 I]
      5 ∠ ArcTan[4/3]
```

Numbers in `ComplexPolar` form can be added, multiplied, etc., then converted using `PolarToComplex`.