# How to transform power of -1 into exponential

Tags: simplifying-expressions

After `FullSimplify`, Mathematica usally gives some coefficients like

```
((-1)^(1/5))
```

But I don't want this form, I want

```
E^(I/5 π)
```

But

```
(-1)^(1/5) /. -1 -> E^(I π)
```

is not working.

So how to transform power of -1 into exponential form?

**PS**

I also want to transform -1 into E^[I π]

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of the more general [16414](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16414) or [20570](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20570).

Comment: `(-1)^(1/5)/.(-1)^x_:>E^(I Pi x)`

Answer (score 6):

```
PowerExpand[(-1)^(1/5), Assumptions -> True]
```

[image]

`Assumptions -> True` is necessary here, which is documented in [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PowerExpand.html).

Comment: Thank you! What if I also want to transform -1 into E^[I π]?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function [JM wrote](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23197/1783) for this task.

```
polarForm[z_] := 
 Module[{rt, f}, If[Im[z] == 0 && Positive[Re[z]], Return[z]];
  rt = Through[{Abs, Arg}[z]];
  f = Which[rt[[1]] == 1, Defer[E^(I #2)] &, rt[[2]] == 1, 
    Defer[#1 E^I] &, True, Defer[#1 E^(I #2)] &]; f @@ rt]
```

For example:

```
polarForm[1 + I]

Sqrt[2] E^((I π)/4)

polarForm[-1]

E^(I π)

polarForm[(-3)^(1/5)]

3^(1/5) E^((I π)/5)
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple replacement is

```
(-1)^(1/5) /. z_ :> Abs[z]*Exp[I*Arg[z]]
```

> E^((I*Pi)/5)

While equivalent for the specific example of (-1)^(1/5), this approach is more general than `PowerExpand`. For example

```
n = 5; 
Prepend[
  Table[{
    x = (-3)^(m/n),
    PowerExpand[x, Assumptions -> True],
    x /. z_ :> Abs[z]*Exp[I*Arg[z]]},
   {m, n - 1}],
  {"x", "PowerExpand", "Rule"}] //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out!