# Display the list of complex roots returned by Solve in their polar form

Tags: complex

If I input:

```
Solve[z^4 == 2 (Cos[2 Pi/3] + I Sin[2 Pi/3])]
```

*Mathematica* returns:

> ```
> {{z -> -(-1 + I Sqrt[3])^(1/4)}, {z -> -I (-1 + I Sqrt[3])^(1/4)}, 
>  {z -> I (-1 + I Sqrt[3])^(1/4)}, {z -> (-1 + I Sqrt[3])^(1/4)}}.
> ```

I want to see these complex numbers in their polar form.  For example, one of the roots in the list is `2^(1/4)*(Cos[Pi/6] + I Sin[Pi/6])`

Comment: see [how-can-i-convert-a-complex-number-into-an-exponent-form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16414/how-can-i-convert-a-complex-number-into-an-exponent-form)  example ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JQP3B.png)

Comment: or [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20570).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots as Cartesian complex numbers.

```
roots = Solve[z^4 == 2 (Cos[2 Pi/3] + I Sin[2 Pi/3])][[All, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {-(-1 + I Sqrt[3])^(1/4), -I (-1 + I Sqrt[3])^(1/4), 
>  I (-1 + I Sqrt[3])^(1/4), (-1 + I Sqrt[3])^(1/4)}
> ```

The roots converted to polar form.

```
 polarRoots = AbsArg /@ roots
```

> ```
> {{2^(1/4), Arg[-(-1 + I*Sqrt[3])^(1/4)]}, 
>  {2^(1/4), Arg[(-I)*(-1 + I*Sqrt[3])^(1/4)]}, 
>  {2^(1/4), Arg[I*(-1 + I*Sqrt[3])^(1/4)]}, 
>  {2^(1/4), Pi/6}}
> ```

These values may not look the same as the representation you were expecting, but to *Mathematica* they really are the same, as can be seen by plotting `polarRoots`.

```
ListPolarPlot[Reverse /@ polarRoots,
  PolarAxes -> True,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[15]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank You!  I am still using version 9.   polarRoots = AbsArg /@ roots   didn't work  but I adapted with: polarRoots = Map[{Abs[#], Arg[#]} &, roots]

Answer (score 1):

Following Nasser's suggestion...

```
polarForm = Expand[# /. z_?NumericQ :> Abs[z] Exp[I Arg[z]]] &;
```

Then

```
 Solve[z^4 == polarForm[ (Cos[2 Pi/3] + I Sin[2 Pi/3])]]
```

(* {{z->-Power[-1, (6)^-1]},{z->Power[-1, (6)^-1]},{z->-(-1)^(2/3)},{z->(-1)^(2/3)}} *)

Comment: But I want to see ALL the roots in their polar form.  I tried this: Map[Abs[z /. # ] Exp[I Arg[z /. #]] &,  Solve[z^4 == 2 (Cos[2 Pi/3] + I Sin[2 Pi/3])]].  I got only one root in its polar form.  The problem seems to be that Arg[z] doesn't seem to work on some of the roots?