# ListPolarPlot does not allow PolarAxes->True or PolarGridLines->True?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am running the personal version of Mathematica 9 on a MacBook Air with OS 10.10.5.

When I try to activate `PolarAxes->True` and/or `PolarGridLines -> True`, I get pages of error messages. This occurs even when I try to replicate existing working examples from this site, such as:

[ListPolarPlot not showing full plot range even with PlotRange -> All](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30001/listpolarplot-not-showing-full-plot-range-even-with-plotrange-all)

Here is an example of my problem:

The following code creates data for a circle in polar coordinates, and correctly plots it using `ListPolarPlot`.

```
dataPoints = 100;
circleData = Table[{counter // N, 0.5}, {counter, 0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/dataPoints}];
ListPolarPlot[circleData, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

However, when I try to set `PolarAxes->True`

```
ListPolarPlot[circleData, Joined -> True, PolarAxes -> True]
```

I just get error messages.

[Wolfram documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPolarPlot.html) for ListPolarPlot says:

> ListPolarPlot has the same options as ListPlot, with the following changes:

`PolarAxes->False` and `PolarGridLines->None`

Does that mean I cannot set either of those options to other values? That seems to contradict working examples I have seen on this site.

I can obviously write my own code to mimic what `PolarAxes` and `PolarGridLines` do, but I am sure that is not the best solution.

(I can print the error messages if that would be helpful. The relevant terms that I see are `DrawPolarAxes` and `DrawPolarAxesDump`. )

Comment: It works correctly here, as it did for belisarius. The statement listing `PolarAxes -> False` and `PolarGridLines -> None` is just giving the *default* values of those options, not stating that other possibilities are not allowed. Are you using 9.0.0 or 9.0.1? It could be a bug in the former.

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101951/3066) also shows that `PolarAxes -> True` works in `ListPolarPlot`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem the user is experiencing can not be reproduced by others.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I get on V9. I suspect a bug or a problem with your local installation. Let's see what other people get.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I get the same with V 10.0