# ListPolarPlot goes crazy when PolarAxes->True

Tags: plotting, bugs, warning-messages

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 9.0.1**

---

I think I am experiencing the same/similar problems as [this user](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102015/listpolarplot-does-not-allow-polaraxes-true-or-polargridlines-true).

Mathematica Version: 9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 20, 2012)

Computer: Mac OS X 10.11.5

When I run the code below, LisPolarPlot works fine until I include the option PolarAxes->True at which point it spits out reams of error messages. Any advice on solving this issue or implementing an alternative to achieve similar results?

```
list = Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi, 0.1}];
ListPolarPlot[list, PolarAxes -> False]
ListPolarPlot[list, PolarAxes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: For reference, what version and OS are you on?

Comment: Good point. Updated question.

Comment: MMA 9.0.1.0 in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit - no error :)

Comment: I can't reproduce it on the same setup as OP  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ot6sv.png

Comment: My colleague who is on an identical setup to me reproduces the error

Comment: @Jasonisnolongerapostdoc you're running different versions; the dates are different. What does `"ReleaseID" /. SystemInformation["Kernel"]` return?

Comment: @Tom what does `"ReleaseID" /. SystemInformation["Kernel"]` return?

Comment: @rcollyer - I get  "9.0.2.0 (4167912, 4167246)" - I can try it on 9.0.0

Comment: @Jasonisnolongerapostdoc ha! that's what I guessed you were running. I can run it here, too, but it will take me a few minutes to unpack 9.0.0.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not I can reproduce it on 9.0.0, or not, I can't reproduce it on later releases, nor can I reproduce it on 8.0.1. So, it seems isolated to a narrow set of builds. So, if possible, upgrade.

Comment: [Can confirm](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HblrN.png) this bug in version 9.0.0.0 - @rcollyer is the upgrade to 9.0.2 free?  If so that seems easier than hunting down a workaround

Comment: @Jasonisnolongerapostdoc I have no clue. Something to contact support about.

Comment: "ReleaseID" /. SystemInformation["Kernel"] returns "9.0.0.0 (3825048, 3824632)"

Comment: I'll ask the IT guys if they can upgrade to 9.0.2, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Perhaps changing `PolarTicks` helps?

Comment: @Tom I'd ask to see if you could upgrade to 10.4.1, but that's just me. :)

Comment: I'd love to, but I think licenses cost thousands of pounds for commercial/research purposes and I'm not in charge of the budget!

Comment: Wolfram said we can upgrade to 9.0.1 for free (they made no mention of 9.0.2)