# how can I modify this function to convert to polar form for any complex expression?

Tags: functions, function-construction, complex, assumptions

The function from another post is to convert a complex number to polar form.

```
polarForm = Expand[# /. z_?NumericQ :> Abs[z] Exp[I Arg[z]]] &
```

Now if I apply that function to this expression it works.

```
In[381]:= (320/12641-(316 I)/12641) E^(1000 I t)  //ComplexExpand
Out[381]= (320 Cos[1000 t])/12641+I (-((316 Cos[1000 t])/12641)+(320 Sin[1000 t])/12641)+(316 Sin[1000 t])/12641
```

However if I apply it the the complex number below (the same one but just expand it in real and imaginary parts) it doesn't work.

```
In[382]:= (320 Cos[1000 t])/12641+I (-((316 Cos[1000 t])/12641)+(320 Sin[1000 t])/12641)+(316 Sin[1000 t])/12641//polarForm
Out[382]= (320/12641-(316 I)/12641) Cos[1000 t]+(316/12641+(320 I)/12641) Sin[1000 t]
```

I thought the problem is due to the variable `t` so I added an assumption that `t` is real but it doesn't work either.

```
In[383]:= $Assumptions=t\[Element]Reals
(320 Cos[1000 t])/12641+I (-((316 Cos[1000 t])/12641)+(320 Sin[1000 t])/12641)+(316 Sin[1000 t])/12641//polarForm
Out[383]= t\[Element]\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]
Out[384]= (320/12641-(316 I)/12641) Cos[1000 t]+(316/12641+(320 I)/12641) Sin[1000 t]
```

Question: how can I modify the `polarForm` function to assume all variables in the expression are real so the function works for any expression?

Comment: Change `Expand` to `ComplexExpand` in `polarForm`?

Comment: @BillWatts I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: 1. What's the "another post"? 2. The sample `In[381]` doesn't match the description "I apply that function to this expression it works", please double check it. 3. "I thought the problem is due to the variable `t`" To some degree, you're right, but `$Assumptions` doesn't have any influence on `NumericQ` because `NumericQ` doesn't have the option `Assumptions`. 4. A even simpler example showing the limitation of `polarForm`: `Clear[a,b]; a + b I // polarForm`.

Comment: @xzczd It's from this. 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16414/how-can-i-convert-a-complex-number-into-an-exponent-form?rq=1
It doesn't work even if I remove `NumericQ`.

Comment: @anhnha What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please show us your modified code and obtained output.

Comment: @xzczd I just deleted `NumericQ` from the `polarForm` function. 
`polarForm = Expand[# /. z :> Abs[z] Exp[I Arg[z]]] &` 
and then applied it to the expression above.

Comment: Once again, what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @xzczd `polarForm1 = Expand[# /. z :> Abs[z] Exp[I Arg[z]]] &;
(320 Cos[1000 t])/12641 + 
  I (-((316 Cos[1000 t])/12641) + (320 Sin[1000 t])/12641) + (316 Sin[
      1000 t])/12641 // polarForm1` and this is the output `(320/12641 - (316 I)/12641) Cos[
   1000 t] + (316/12641 + (320 I)/12641) Sin[1000 t]`

Comment: `z :>` should be `z_ :>`

Comment: @xzczd ok but still not works. 
this is the output `E^(I Arg[(320 Cos[1000 t])/12641 + 
    I (-((316 Cos[1000 t])/12641) + (320 Sin[1000 t])/12641) + (
    316 Sin[1000 t])/12641])
  Abs[(320 Cos[1000 t])/12641 + 
   I (-((316 Cos[1000 t])/12641) + (320 Sin[1000 t])/12641) + (
   316 Sin[1000 t])/12641]`

Comment: Once again, what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Because it involves `Arg`? Or something else?

Comment: well I sent the result above. If it works then it should be in polar form but if you look at the result I sent above, it still has imaginary numbers in the result.

Comment: OK, so by "doesn't work" you mean you want the `Abs[z]` and `Arg[z]` evaluate to something doesn't **explicitly** involve `I`. Then `ComplexExpand` as shown in my answer is necessary. BTW, now I guess you probably see why your question doesn't attract much attention.

Comment: @xzczd why does it not?

Comment: 1. The most important part: the code sample isn't simplified enough. (As you can see, `a+b I` is capable of reproducing the issue. ) Lengthier sample is less attractive. 2. The description "doesn't work" is vague and is more likely to push people away. 3. Though you quote function `polarForm` from another post, you don't give the link, this leads to the impression the question isn't well prepared. 4. The code sample `In[381]` is wrong, this again leads to the impression the question isn't well prepared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not `AbsArg`?:

```
(320 Cos[1000 t])/12641 + 
    I (-((316 Cos[1000 t])/12641) + (320 Sin[1000 t])/12641) + (316 Sin[1000 t])/12641//
    AbsArg // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // #[[1]] Exp[I #[[2]]] &

(*
E^(I ArcTan[(320 Cos[1000 t])/12641 + (316 Sin[1000 t])/
    12641, -((316 Cos[1000 t])/12641) + (320 Sin[1000 t])/12641]) Sqrt[((
    320 Cos[1000 t])/12641 + (316 Sin[1000 t])/12641)^2 + (-((316 Cos[1000 t])/12641) +(
    320 Sin[1000 t])/12641)^2]
 *)
```